# Visual C project in the Xilinx Microblaze

Tags: c, xilinx

Can I embed the C code from Visual C project in the Xilinx Microblaze? I have already created the EDK design of hardware and want to import my Visual studio based design of FIR filter into the Xilinx SDK. I don't know how to do it. Is it even possible? Any tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently I am playing with Spartan06 from xilinx. As far as I can understand that you **cannot** import Visual C project to Xilinx Microblaze.

This is because you need to use a cross compiler to target the Microblaze processor. Xilinx uses the CodeSourcery's gcc to do that. That is why you need to use the SDK to compile the program for Microblaze.

To function properly in their board, you need to write correct values to correct registers ( as per your design ); that is where Xilinx C library will come handy.

Also it will be cumbersome for you to setup the Xilinx C library in Visual C.

hope this helps,
regards

Comment: Thanks; So, Can I add the *.C files from VC to the SDK, and can complile using the GCC ?. As far as I know, the GCC is for Unix/Linux platforms. How much is the Xilinx C library different from the normal C programming.

Comment: Yes you can add c file to the sdk and compile it using gcc. CodeSourcy's gcc is a cross compiler for arm architecture and they have both windows & linux variant of their gcc. It doesn't matter which platform you use to code, the target binary will be for arm architecture only. 

Xilinx made macros & function to access their register, read & write from/to them.

Think like that, strcpy copies the char string, you can also write your version bypassing the strcpy. And that would certainly take time and more prone to error.